# SWIFT iOS9: How to recognize a click on the X button of the UISearchBar

Tags: ios, swift, uisearchbar

I have to change a boolean variable value when the user clears the word that he was searching for. He clears it when he taps the X icon on the right side of the search bar.

I don't know how to get this action. The functions related to search bar only recognizes clicks on the cancel button, bookmarks button and search results button.

How can I do that using Swift 2 on iOS9 devices?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can implement this delegate function of UISearchBarDelegate:

```
func searchBar(_ searchBar: UISearchBar, textDidChange searchText: String) {
  if  searchText.count == 0 {
    //call your func
  }
}
```

as the documentation says:

```
Discussion
This method is also invoked when text is cleared from the search text field.
```

Answer (score 0):

Swift 4 `UISearchResultsUpdating` delegate method:

```
func updateSearchResults(for searchController: UISearchController) 
{
    print("updating: \(searchController.searchBar.text!)")

    if (searchController.searchBar.text?.isEmpty)! 
    {
       print("empty")
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if let textfield = searchBar.value(forKey: "searchField") as? UITextField 
     textfield.delegate = self
}
```

First you can assign delegate as this and then in **UITextFieldDelegate** method

```
func textFieldShouldClear(_ textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
    searchBar.text = ""
    searchBar.resignFirstResponder()
    return true
}
```